# Apache Rewrite Simple Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I just want rewrite the languages (nothing more): en > lang/en, es > lang/es ... etc.

```
http://domain.com/en  >  http://domain.com/lang/en 
http://domain.com/es  >  http://domain.com/lang/es 
http://domain.com/en/places?User=1  >  http://domain.com/lang/en/places?User=1
http://domain.com/es/places?User=1  >  http://domain.com/lang/es/places?User=1
```

My current .htacces is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en(.*)$ lang/en$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^es(.*)$ lang/es$1 [NC,L]
```

Please, Is right this?
I see the final URL: http://domain.com/lang/en/places?User=1 and I want the browser shows http://domain.com/en/places?User=1. Can be it possible?

Thanks very much!

Comment: There's nothing there that's redirecting the browser, you may be accessing a directory or what apache thinks is a directory and is redirecting you to a trailing slash. Are you sure the URL that shows up in your browser's address bar doesn't end with a slash?

Answer (score 0):

You want the browser shows the original URL? it needs "passthrough". Try to change the "[NC]" to "[PL]"

Comment: Thanks for your reply @hongtium! 
My big doubt is if this htaccess will works right for this simple rule.
[PL] returns an Internal Server Error :O

Comment: @user512663 that's because there is no flag called `PL`, it's `PT` but that's not even what you want since it only puts the URI back into the pipeline.